# Jquery Acordian Error with Other Jquery Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I created 3 elements: slideshow, draggable slider and accordian all using Jquery.  Each one was created as a stand alone so I can reuse the code in any project.  All work perfectly seperately.  The draggable and slideshow had one conflict I was able to resolve...but once I added trhe accordian, it is not working.  I am getting an error in the combined page of:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function

But on the stand alone page, I do not get this error.  I placed this code in the head of both documents:
Here is all file and library links (Some are currently commented out as I try to troubleshoot the problem:

```
 <!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<!--<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>-->
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/jquery.bxslider.css">
<!-- Scrollyeah js and css files -->
<!--<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/scrollyeah.css">
<!--<script src="js/scrollyeah.js"></script>-->
<!-- Begin Accordian Links -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/selectivizr.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/accordian.css">
            <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true
    });
});
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true
    });
});
</script>
```

**Any ideas of why this is happening?**  All that happens on the combined page is it renders the html with no styling to the accordians divs.

Comment: There must be clash of jquery version, use jQuery.noConflict()

Comment: I did that t fix the first error I was having.  It worked and solved that problem, but not this problem.

Comment: `TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function` means your jquery-UI library is not getting executed properly

Comment: Can you please add an example of how you are referencing your jQuery / UI scripts. Are you referencing multiple versions of jQuery? Is the UI library being added *after* the jQuery library in all instances?

Comment: Here is all lines of js and jq:

Answer (score 0):

It should br $(..).accordion();
Not $(..).accordion . *Notice the paranthesis at the end.*

Comment: It does have parenthesis on the end.  The error was copied and pasted from the "inspect element" console. If that was the case, why does it work on one page and not the other?